# Drupal 7 website not loading (Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 619)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am getting the following error with my drupal website.

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 619"

I have checked the system table and status for user.module is set to 1 .

Can anyone suggest what could be the error?

Regards,

Comment: Related: [Call to undefined function menu_load() in …/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/82577/1908) at Drupal SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of PHP do you use with your xampp installation? Have you disabled/enabled Zend Optimizer or other PHP modules just before the error appeared? And which version of drupal causes this error?

Comment: I am using XAMPP 1.7.4  [PHP: 5.3.5] .. I Am using Drupal 7 ... I am not sure about the zend or other modules but if I go to phpinfo() I cant find any zend text on doing ctrl-f..

Comment: Have you installed any new modules just before the error appeared or have you upgraded Drupal (i.e. 7.0 -> 7.4) and if yes, have you ran update.php?

Comment: no this is a fresh installation and I dont have any module other then oracle driver: you can refer to exact steps I performed in following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729547/issues-post-installation-drupal-7-and-oracle-driver-1-6

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tips:

- make sure your Drupal core has all the files in the right place (especially user module),
- make sure your imported database is in UTF-8 format,
- upgrade your Drupal core to the latest version (`drush fr && drush up drupal`)
- clear all your caches (`drush -y cc all`), including your memcached (`killall memcached`),
- rebuild your registry by using [Registry Rebuild][1],
- if you're using modules which are implementing `drupal_bootstrap()` (such as Secure Site), disable them,
- try disabling your PHP cache engines (such as XCache, Zend optimizer) to see if that's the problem,
- test it on different environment/machine,
- eventually restore your database from the point where it was working before